# I can't see the icon I added to the html page on the screen

Tags: html, css, web

I can't see the logo icon that I added to the html page on my web page. I'm still very new to this and don't know what to do without clear guidance.

I am trying to build Amazon Clone with Html and CSS. I am getting help from a video. Even if I follow the same steps, I cannot see the location icon that I added to the screen. What could I have done wrong?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #0f1111;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("amazon_logo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.border {
  border: 1.5px solid transparent;
}

.border:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid white;
}


/**box-2**/

.add-first {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.add-second {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.add-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<link rel=" stylesheet href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css " integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="
        anonymous " referrerpolicy="no-referrer ">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet " href="style.css " -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="nav-logo border">
        <div class="logo">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-address">
        <p class="add-first">Deliver to </p>
        <div class="add-icon">
          <i class="fa-light fa-location-dot"></i>
          <p class="add-sec">Türkiye</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the link element for Font Awesome. It has extra characters in it which break it.

Comment: A good editor is critical to working with any sort of code. It'll help you spot problems like this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not including the stlye.css in the HTML file.

I see it's been commented out:

```
<!--link rel="stylesheet "href="style.css" -->
```

Try uncommenting it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet " href="style.css">
```

Comment: Actually, it appears in my codes, I even made a few edits in my css file. I deleted and re-edited the link but nothing changed.

Comment: What appears in your code?

Comment: Sorry, problem solved. The problem was a mistake I made in the quotation marks. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help, could you help upvote if my solution helped you?